# Prove that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le|x-y|$ for all $x$ and $y$.

Tags: real-analysis, periodic-functions

Let $f(x) = |x|$ for $x \in [-1,1]$ and extend $f$ to all of $\mathbb R$ by requiring $f(x+2)=f(x)$. Prove that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le|x-y|$ for all $x$ and $y$.

This is easy to observe on a graph but my proof is long and a bit tedious. Just curious if there is a quick/elegant way?

Comment: Partition the domain into nonoverlapping intervals of the form $I_n = [2n-1, 2n+1]$. You really only have two cases to consider. Case 1: $x$ and $y$ are in the same interval $I_n$, Case 2: $x$ and $y$ are in adjacent intervals. (If they are in nonadjacent intervals, then the distance between them is at least $2$, whereas $|f(x) - f(y)|$ clearly never exceeds $1$.)

Comment: Probably the first observation you should make is that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq 1$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, so if $|x-y|\geq 1$, you're done.  This reduces the problem to checking the $|x-y|<1$ case, which you can do by moving back to $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a reasonably quick way based on the observation that  $f(x) = \min_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |x-2n|$.

We have $|x-2n| \le |y-2n| +|x-y|$ for all $n$, and so
$f(x) \le |y-2n| +|x-y|$ for all $n$. Now choose $n$ such that $f(y) = |y-2n|$,
then we have $f(x)-f(y) \le |x-y|$. Swapping the roles of $x,y$ yields the 
desired result.

Comment: This is lovely, no case splitting

Answer (score 1):

Archemedian property implies for all $x$ there is an $a_x \in [-1, 1]$ and a $k_x \in \mathbb Z$ such that $x = 2k_x + a_x$, so $f(x) = f(a_x) = |a_x|$.

$| x - y| = |2k_x + a_x - 2k_y - a_y| = 2|k_x - k_y|+ |a_x - a_y| \ge |a_x - a_y|$

So $|f(x) - f(y)| = ||a_x| - |a_y|| \le |a_x - a_y|$.  As $a_x, a_y \in [-1, 1] \implies |a_x - a_y| \le |1 - (-1)| = 2$.  So$ |f(x) - f(y)| = |a_x - a_y| \le |x - y|$

Comment: I suppose it is worth mentioning that $k>j$ is wlog. This is similar to my proof.

Comment: Maybe.  Maybe not.  I put |k-j| in absolute signs to allow all posibilities. However I was very lax with absolute value calculations and the triangle inequality.  I didn't claim anything that can't be claimed and shown but I relied on common geometric intuition then precise verification.

Comment: I meant to point out that $|2k_x + a_x - 2k_y - a_y| < 2|k_x - k_y|+ |a_x - a_y|$ if $k_x - k_y < 0$ and $a_x - a_y > 0$, so the proof would not work in that case.

Comment: I was taking it for granted that 2|kx - ky| is an integer multiple of 2 whereas |ax - ay| <= 2 so the integer multiple is either greater than |ax - xy|, 0, or less than -|ax - xy|