# $\phi(x) = |x|$ for $x\in [-1,1]$ and $\phi(x+2)=\phi(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Show $|\phi(t) - \phi(s)|\leq |t-s|$

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Define a function $\phi$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by $\phi(x) = |x|$ for $x\in [-1,1]$ and $\phi(x+2)=\phi(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Show $|\phi(t) - \phi(s)|\leq |t-s|$.

Attempt: for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $\phi(x)$ =  $\bigg\{\begin{array}{cc} |-1 + \{x\}| \ \text{,if} \ [x]=1 (\mod2) \\ \{x\}\ \ , \text{if}\ \ [x] = 0(\mod 2)\end{array}$

where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$ and $[x]$ is the greatest integer of $x$.

can't proceed further

Comment: I've edited your answer to adjust the domain, please make sure I've guessed correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le|x-y|$ for all $x$ and $y$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1499317/prove-that-fx-fy-lex-y-for-all-x-and-y) – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f(x)%20%3D%20%7Cx%7C%24%2C%20%24f(x%2B2)%20%3D%20f(x)%24&p=1)

Comment: Thanks!  I got it